# Show passwords with input type password in backend application

Tags: forms, symfony-1.4

I'm using symfony 1.4 with doctrine, I generated a User module using the admin generator and I want to show the password field as an input of type password for the edit and the create forms. All the solutions I found on the internet refers to symfony 1.1 or 1.2 and the use of the input_tag_password helper that is deprecated in symfony 1.4. Also I tried to use the type property for the field in the generator.yml file of the module with no results.

Any clue to this will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it using a partial and editing the generator.yml file:

```
<div class="password_field">
  <div>
    <label for="password_field">Password</label>
    <div class="content">
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password_field" />     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in generator.yml:

```
  edit:    
    display: [username, _password, email_address]
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it worked for me. If someone has a better answer please share it :)